# Can openpyxl make Excel believe that its worksheet is fully calculated?

Tags: excel, openpyxl, calculation

I receive spreadsheets full of user-defined formulas I don't have access to (some DLL).  Because I'm only interested in the values, that's ok - I can use the cached values.  What I typically do is hardcode such workbooks using `openpyxl` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(sys.argv[1],data_only=True,keep_vba=False)
wb.save(sys.argv[1])
```

Now the workbook contains only values, no formulas. Great.

However, often, when I am linking to such workbooks, Excel alerts me that the worbook hasn't been recalculated and I need to click OK hundreds of times.  Which is silly because there are no formulas to calculate.

Is there any way in `openpyxl` to trick Excel into realising that such workbooks are 'fully calculated' and are in no need of re-calculation?  At the moment I have to open the worbook in Excel, hit F9 and re-save.  But because the workbooks are large, I would rather do it in an automated process.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able set the "calculation properties" for the workbook.

Something like:

```
wb.calculation.calcMode = "manual"
```

should work. But you might need to play around with the options to get it to work how you need it.

NB. Who knows what the macros want to do that you're keeping in the workbook.

Comment: I'm sorry, I obviously wasn't clear enough.  I want to avoid opening the file at all.  It is very large, and I only need 100 or so calculated values from predictable locations in the file.  Opening the file (which arrives from a colleague fresh each day, full of formulas) is slow, so I (without opening it, but simply using openpyxl) create a hard-code  (values only) version of this file and link to this; but then I get a whole lot of alerts from excel.
Your solution requires me to open in Excel the very file I don't want to open.  I only want to cherry-pick some (about 100) values from it.

Comment: I think my question can be asked differently in a clearer way.  I'll try again.

Comment: @Charlie_Clark got your comment too late.  I think my new question is better.  It is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255160/how-does-excel-know-that-a-file-was-not-recalculated-before-it-was-last-saved