# How does Excel know that a file "was not recalculated before it was last saved". Can I trick Excel into thinking the opposite?

Tags: excel, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When linking workbooks in Excel, I often get an error like:

> Links to `xxxx.xlsx` were not updated because `xxxx.xlsx` was not recalculated before it was last saved

This error pops up once for every linked value, which means in my case about 100 alerts I need to press OK for.  Mysteriously, this alert comes even if `xxxx.xlsx` contains no formulas and hence no recalculation at all: it's completely full of values only.

So how does Excel know that a file has not been recalculated before saving?  Is it looking at a particular xml value inside the ZIP file (xlsx) which I could tamper with? Is it looking at open date vs modified date that I could circumvent with the `touch` linux command?  I'd like a solution Using the command line ubuntu if possible (I run windows WSL), so that I can use a script.

And what's more, `xxxx.xlsx` is really big, which over network (thanks COVID) at home is slow to open / recalc / save.  So I really don't want to ever open this file in Excel.

Any ideas?

Comment: there is a property that may try to calculate the workbook before saving. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculatebeforesave  But not sure if this is your case

Comment: This property instructs excel (if open) what to do in the future.  But it won't tell me what has been done with a file in the past.

Comment: What I mean is that Excel will recalculate at closing, even if recalculation are not needed, because of this property

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this macro to your PERSONAL.XLSB file and then running it. It will ask you to select a file and then open it without allowing links to update.

```
Sub OpenWithoutUpdatingLinks()

    Dim strFileName As String

    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If strFileName <> "" Then Workbooks.Open FileName:=strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False

End Sub
```

This will allow you to open the file you're working on without getting the message about updating links.

However, if you actually need the links to update or need to create more links, then you need the linked file to be recalculated.

Let us know if you need instructions on adding a macro to your personal file and running it.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to update the links to a new xlsx file which has been generated by a script, so I can't use this.